# Montgomery multiplication VHDL Implementation

Tags: math, cryptography, vhdl, integer-arithmetic, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to create a modular arithmetic operation in this case:

```
x*y mod n
```

As far as I have read the fastest way to do it is using the Montgomery multiplication, but I cant understand how that is actually done in other to implement it in hardware using VHDL.

Has someone been able to do it or have any library that enables me to use it?

Comment: @DuncanJones thanks for the many edits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic shift and add modular multiplication can be found [here](http://opencores.org/websvn,filedetails?repname=BasicRSA&path=/BasicRSA/trunk/rtl/vhdl/modmult.vhd) as a part of [this](http://opencores.org/project,basicrsa) open cores project.

[Here's](http://opencores.org/project,rsa_512) another project that is using the Montgomery multiplication.