# VHDL simulation stuck in for loop

Tags: loops, vhdl, multiplication

I'm doing simulation testing for some VHDL I wrote and when I run it in ModelSim it gets stuck.  When I hit 'break' it has an arrow pointing to the `For` loop in the following function:

```
function MOD_3 (a, b, c : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0)) return UNSIGNED is

  VARIABLE x : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0) := TO_UNSIGNED(1, 1024);
  VARIABLE y : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0) := a;
  VARIABLE b_temp : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0) := b;

begin

  for I in 0 to 1024 loop
    if b_temp > 0 then
      if b_temp MOD 2 = 1 then
        x := (x * y) MOD c;
      end if;
      y := (y * y) MOD c;
      b_temp := b_temp / 2;
    else
      exit;
    end if;
  end loop;

  return x MOD c;

end function;
```

I originally had this as a `while` loop which I realize is not good for synthesizing.  So I converted it to a `for` loop with the condition that `b_temp` is greater than 0.  `b_temp` is a 1024-bit `unsigned` and so if it is the largest number that could be represented by 1024 bits and divided in half (which I do in each iteration) 1024 times, shouldn't it definitely be 0?

I have a feeling my problem lies in the large multiplications...if I comment out `x := (x * y) MOD c` and `y := (y * y) MOD c` then it exits the loop.  So the only thing I can think of is it takes too long to carry out these 1024-bit multiplications?  If this is the case, is there any built-in way I can optimize this to make it faster, or is my only option to implement something like Karatsuba multiplication, etc...?

Comment: Put a Report statement in there that prints the loop counter. The loop may just be taking longer than you think. Also, which sim are you using? It may be worth trying others. Also, are there any constraints on the value of C? If you think `*` is slow, you haven't benchmarked `mod`... (don't worry about `mod 2` though, it ought to be optimised)

Comment: I agree with Brian, `mod` is performed by division, which is eons slower than multiplication. If your goal is synthesis, you are doing it wrong. The `mod` operation is not synthesizable (except probably by 2), the multiplication of 2 1024-bits number would take an ungodly amount of embedded multiplier and give a very-very large critical path. Even worse, you chain up to 1025 of those multiplication on 2 different variables, so those ungodly amount are multiplied by 2050 and 1025 respectively! For synthesis, your algorithm needs to be bit serial to reuse the same hardware.

Comment: Minor correction : `mod` by small constants (not just 2, but 28 for example) is synthesisable, at least with Xilinx XST. And an additional note : "bit serial" here may mean 1024 * 1 operations are possible. I'd go further and use 1024*16 for good use of the multipliers. I don't have a clear idea of the best way to implement `mod` beyond noting that since C's only use is for a LOT of Mod operations, you can afford to precompute 1/C and divide by reciprocal multiplication. This would need testing its numeric  properties, you may need a 2048-bit accurate reciprocal to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: @Brian I stand corrected, I didn't know that. I tested it though, works well for `unsigned(7 downto 0) mod 3`, even for `unsigned(7 downto 0) mod unsigned(2 downto 0)`, but the same on a `unsigned(255 downto 0)` failed (got impatient after 1 hour waiting synthesis result). I can't find any documentation about it for XST, but it does seems it is implemented as a series of comparators and adder/subtractors and has horrible critical path.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I did mention synthesis but the furthest I'm going is simulation using ModelSim SE.  The only constraint on C is that it is always going to be 1024 bits and possibly prime.  I'll attempt to implement the pre-computation of C to see if it helps.  Aside from that, it sounds like I really have no option other than to implement new mod and multiplication algorithms optimized for large bit sizes?

Comment: After reading some more on the topic, [Montgomery Arithmetic](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/519.pdf) sounds like it may be a good solution to this problem.

Comment: Serious suggestion : write your code agnostic or generic in wordlength, and work on it at (say) 128 bit, before moving the final solution to 1024. Might be a faster way of making progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm of the opinion implementing a Montgomery multiplier in numeric_std function calls may not improve simulation as much as you'd like (while giving synthesis eligibility).

The issue is the number of dynamically elaborated subprogram calls vs. their operand sizes vs. fitting in your CPU-running-Modelsim's L1/L2*/L3* caches.

It does do wonders for targeting synthesis in an FPGA or a SIMD GPU implementation.

See [Subversion Repositories BasicRSA](http://opencores.org/websvn,listing?repname=BasicRSA&path=%2FBasicRSA%2Ftrunk%2Frtl%2Fvhdl%2F&rev=4) file modmult.vhd (which has a generic size). I successfully converted this to using numeric_std[_unsigned].

If I recall correctly this appears inspired by 
a Masters thesis ([Efficient Hardware Architectures for Modular Multiplication](https://www.emsec.rub.de/media/crypto/attachments/files/2010/04/dnamanorthesis.pdf)) by David Narh Amanor in 2005 outlining a Java and a VHDL implementation in various word sizes.

I found the OpenCores implementation mentioned in a Stackoverflow question ([Montgomery multiplication VHDL Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983541/montgomery-multiplication-vhdl-implementation)) and found the generic sized version in the SVN repository (the downloadable version is 16 bit) and the mention of the thesis in [A 1024 – Bit Implementation of the Faster Montgomery Multiplier Using VHDL](http://www.aphysrev.org/index.php/aphysrev/article/viewFile/191/110) (by David Narh Anamor, the original link having expired). Note the quoted FPGA implementation performance under 42 usec.

Notice the length 1024 version specified by a generic would still be performing dynamically elaborated function calls with length 1024 operands (although not the "*"s, the "mod"s or the "/"s. You'd still be doing millions of function calls with dynamically elaborated (passed on an expression stack) 1024 bit parameters. We're simply changing how many millions of large parameter subroutine calls and how long they can take.

And that also brings up the possibility of an integer vector implementation (bignum equivalent) in VHDL, which would potential increase simulation performance even more (and you're likely in uncharted territory here).

A subprogram based version of the OpenCores model using variable parameters would be telling. (Whether or not you can impress anyone showing them a simulation model executing, or whether there's this looong pause interrupted by everyone taking furtive glances at the wall clock and looking bored).