# How to multiply two 1024-bit unsigned integers with very limited resources ( BASYS 2)

Tags: cryptography, vhdl, verilog, fpga

I will take two 1024-bit unsigned integers through serial communication ( 8-bit by 8-bit), convert ASCII to binary, then multiply them to form an output of 2048-bit. The main problem that I have to do multiplication operation with a very small-area FPGA board ( BASYS 2).

The multiplication speed is not an important criteria for me, I can wait a relatively long time ( ~ 1 sec ) to get the correct multiplication result. 
Here is the resources information of my FPGA:
https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/basys3:basys3_ss.pdf

What is a simple and area-effective way to do this? 
a 1024-bit to 1024-bit adder takes alone around %53 of my area usage!

Comment: See [VHDL simulation stuck in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676413/vhdl-simulation-stuck-in-for-loop/30681595#30681595). Can you ask a specific programming question? *What is a simple and area-effective way to do this?* is not a specific programming question.

Comment: See [Novel algorithms and hardware architectures for Montgomery Multiplication over GF(p)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/696.pdf).

Comment: Shift and conditionally add for 1024 steps. How much space does a shift-by-one-bit take? How much space does counting 1024 steps take?

Comment: @user1155120: You jumped the gun. He hasn't asked about modular multiplication. Keep your powder dry, that will almost certainly be his next question ;)

Comment: Can you show the usage of slices, LUTs and FFs for your 1024bit adder? Serial binary adder may reduce the usage.

Comment: I am open for your suggestions for 256-bit x 256-bit multiplier as well for the same board. The area usage exceeds %200 of the slices. I can wait for several thousands of clock cycles to get the correct result.

Comment: I have tried to use Simulink HDL Coder, but it can only support up to 32-bit unsigned integers!

Comment: The doc of your board says you have 4 hardware 18x18 multipliers. You definitely should use them, cutting your vectors in these 18 bit slices. And using the memory for temps storage for a smaller sized added sound like a good idea too.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are certain that a true 1024 x 1024 multiplier really is needed (in many applications, something much cheaper will suffice). Maybe this is stating the obvious, but as a starting point I would try a very simple shift-add. Something like this would work (and I'm sure you can optimize it further to meet your needs):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity wide_mult is
generic (
    A_BITS          : positive := 1024;
    B_BITS          : positive := 1024
);
port (
    clk             : in std_logic;
    -- Input
    in_valid        : in std_logic;
    in_a            : in unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
    in_b            : in unsigned(B_BITS-1 downto 0);
    -- Output
    out_valid       : out std_logic;
    out_prod        : out unsigned(A_BITS+B_BITS-1 downto 0)
);
end wide_mult;

architecture rtl of wide_mult is

    signal shifted_a    : unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
    signal shifted_b    : unsigned(A_BITS+B_BITS-1 downto 0);
    signal progress     : std_logic_vector(A_BITS-1 downto 0);

    signal sum          : unsigned(A_BITS+B_BITS-1 downto 0);

begin

    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            -- Cycle 1
            if in_valid = '1' then
                -- Initialize
                shifted_a <= in_a;
                shifted_b <= resize(in_b, A_BITS+B_BITS);
                progress <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, A_BITS));
            else
                -- Shift
                shifted_a <= shift_right(shifted_a, 1);
                shifted_b <= shift_left(shifted_b, 1);
                progress <= progress(A_BITS-2 downto 0) & '0';
            end if;

            -- Cycle 2 - Accumulate sum
            out_valid <= progress(A_BITS-1);
            if progress(0) = '1' then
                -- Init sum
                if shifted_a(0) = '0' then
                    sum <= (others => '0');
                else
                    sum <= shifted_b;
                end if;
            elsif shifted_a(0) = '1' then
                -- Accumulate
                sum <= sum + shifted_b;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    out_prod <= sum;

end rtl;
```

Your device is very small. If the simple shift-add doesn't even get close to fitting, then this might indicate that you need to change your approach. Since you have an enormous amount of time to do this sum, then perhaps you could offload it to a nearby CPU?

Comment: *a 1024-bit to 1024-bit adder takes alone around %53 of my area usage!* `sum` and `shifted_b` are length `A_BITS + B_BITS` (2048) where `sum <= sum + shifted_b;`.  It's guaranteed not to fit. Also note signal `a` is not evaluated in your architecture and `progress` as a counter would reduce FPGA utilization.

Comment: I guess I edited to remove the signal `a` while you were still writing this comment. The "change your approach" part of my answer covers your "guaranteed not to fit" comment. Perhaps surprisingly, a counter will not necessarily reduce FPGA utilization. In a device I was working with recently (for a very similar problem), trial implementations showed a counter only reduced utilization for counts exceeding several thousand! Of course, this will ultimately depend on the device being used (hence the "you can optimize it further to meet your needs" part of my answer).

Comment: Thanks Harry, although I get used to write in Verilog. I checked your code, and it consumes %102 of the Slices for 256-bit x 256-bit. I scaled down my multiplication target to 256-bit for this stage. Your code seemed to be very close to fit my FPGA. Any idea to design a low-area using adder?

Comment: @utdlegend I have never thought about this. Yes, if we could replace the adder with, for example, a cheaper multi-cycle adder, then you could surely make it fit. I'll think about it. Maybe someone else here knows a good solution.

Comment: @utdlegend I think Hiroto Kagotani's suggestion to use a serial binary adder could be a very good way to go.

Comment: You may not believe. But my serial adder took more area than the pre-defined Verilog addition operator ! I am really at no-way-out position

Comment: I just tried the same thing in VHDL and got the same result. This is an interesting problem. I would love to see a working solution, but I'm also a bit stuck now.

Comment: I have not tried but I think it should fit easily if you do it all 8x8 bit at a time. But! Make sure all the intermediate numbers are read from and written back in BRAM. A lot more timed coding, but not wasting lots and lots of registers on al this. I write Verilog and I might give that a try just for fun.

Comment: Ah yes, using BRAM is definitely the way to go. @utdlegend do you need to access the full 2048-bit result in parallel? I think the best implementation will depend on what you need to do with the result.

Comment: The FPGA used has 18x18 hardware multipliers. They definitely should help!